# Cypress - Controlling which tests to run - Using Cypress for seeding

Tags: javascript, cypress

In the Integrations-folder I currently have 4 folders:

```
|- seeding [Folder1]
|  |- seeding1
|  |- seeding2
|  |- seeding3
|  |- ...
|
|- testing-feature-1 [Folder2]
|  |- test1
|  |- test2
|  |- test3
|  |- ...
|
|- testing-feature-2 [Folder3]
|  |- test4
|  |- test5
|  |- test6
|  |- ...
|
|- testing-feature-3 [Folder4]
|  |- test7
|  |- test8
|  |- test9
|  |- ...
```

In my head, more 'testing-feature-x'-folders will come with time.

---

I would like to be able to control which folders to run. Right now I can either run 'All tests' or a single one. Am I the only one missing the 'Run specs in folder'?! Or tick-boxes, to select which tests to run?

Here are a couple of scenarios, where this would be useful:

- Feature 2 has been remade. I would like to run all tests in the 'testing-feature-2'-folder. 
  **How to achieve it currently**: It can be done with this terminal-command: 
  `npx cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/testing-feature-2/**/*' --browser canary --no-exit`
  This is obviously doable, - but still...
- Feature 2 and 3 has been remade. I would like to run all tests in 'testing-feature-2'- and 'testing-feature-3'-folder. 

  **How to achieve it currently**: It can be done with these two terminal-commands: 
  `npx cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/testing-feature-2/**/*' --browser canary --no-exit`
  `npx cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/testing-feature-3/**/*' --browser canary --no-exit`
  Slightly more annoying. But still do-able.
- About to launch a completely new version. I would like to run all tests except the 'seeding'-folder (possibly over and over, if something plays up). 

  **How to achieve it currently**: In order to do this, I need to move the 'seeding'-folder out of the Integration-folder (temporarily). And then I can run all tests. But if a single feature plays up, then I'm back at the terminal. 
  Fairly annoying. Lot of footwork. But still do-able.

Are there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with the help of some npm scripts, to save you repeatedly typing tedious commands.

In your package.json do something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:open:feature-1": "cypress open --config integrationFolder=tests/cypress/integration/feature-1",
    "cypress:open:feature-2": "cypress open --config integrationFolder=tests/cypress/integration/feature-2"
}
```

`npm run cypress:open` will run tests in the `integration` folder

`npm run cypress:open-feature-1` will run tests in the `integration/feature-1` folder

You can put your seeding functions into `cypress/support/index.js` and add them to the global object, something like this:

```
global.school = () => {
  faker.seed(123) // Seeding faker means you get the same details every time
  return {
    _id: faker.random.number(),
    name: `${faker.address.city()} School`,
    slug: faker.lorem.word(),
    email: 'demo@ccc.me',
    password: 'password'
  }
}
```

In your test script you can invoke this function with a line like this:

```
const s = school() // Get a fresh object that looks like a school
```

I hope that helps