# Check if file exists in Cypress (or JavaScript). Making a conditional login-command

Tags: cypress

I'm having a huge manual login-process that I've automated with a Cypress-command, that I can run like this:

```js
  it('Do something as an authenticated user', () => {
    cy.runManualLogin();
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl'));
    // Now I can do something as a logged in user
  });
```

But the `cy.runManualLogin` takes 2 minutes to complete. When it completes, it writes the contents of the auth-cookies to a temporary file. So I can later on simply login by running: `cy.storeAuthCookiesFromTmpFile();`.
But that is only if the manual login has been completed!

So if I'm in doubt if I've logged in, then I would (currently) have to run `cy.runManualLogin()` again, to make sure that I don't make a flakey test, that fails if the user hasn't logged in. And all of this makes the test-suite take forever to complete.

Ideally, I would like to make another command like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("logInUser", () => {
  let pathToAuthCookies = 'cypress/fixtures/dev/tmp/auth-cookies.json';
  if( ! fileExists( pathToAuthCookies ) ){
    cy.runManualLogin();
  } else {
    cy.storeAuthCookiesFromTmpFile();
  } 
});
```

This way, then I can simply run `cy.logInUser()` everywhere - which will then run the tedious (and necessary) manual login the first time. And in subsequent runs, simply store the cookies and save the long process.

### Solution attempt 1: Using cy.readFile

This didn't work, since it throws an assertion-error when it fails. And I could try to setup some handler for that and mute it, but I'm not sure if I'll then mute later warnings as well. It all seemed like a wrong direction.

### Solution attempt 2: Trying to write a vanilla-JS helper function for it

I haven't dealt with file-handling locally in JavaScript before. I tried a couple of things:

- `return fetch( url ).then( (response) => { ... } );`
- `let myFile = new File("path/to/file.txt"); ... myFile.exists();`

... but I couldn't get any of these attempts to work.
Also knowing that it should be wrapped in a promise as well, to get the timing right for Cypress as well.

### Solution attempt 3: Using `cy-verify-download`

I considered try to find a library for this, such as this: [cy-verify-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cy-verify-downloads). But it seems excessive to add an entire dependency like this, just for this 'small' task. So I didn't try to implement it.

### Solution attempt 4: Control sequence of tests running

For a while I thought I could have some 'initial tests', that preps all the temporary-files and such, and then [making sure to run them first, whenever the entire suite runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662226/cypress-controlling-which-tests-to-run-using-cypress-for-seeding). But this was a mess to maintain and didn't solve the problem.

### Solution attempt 5: Do it with a `require`-statement

I tried something like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("logInUser", () => {
  let fileExists;
  try {
    let pathToFile = '../path/to/file';
    let file = require( pathToFile );
    fileExists = true;
  } catch (e) {
    fileExists = false
  }
  
  if( fileExists ){
    cy.runManualLogin();
  } else {
    cy.storeAuthCookiesFromTmpFile();
  }
}
```

That seemed to work at one point, but seized to do so again, for unknown reasons.

---

I've noted the combination of login-commands here: [Login to WordPress using Cypress, without using the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64174176/1766219).

Comment: Did you already consider to store the info into the global store ? or with `cy.session`

Comment: I didn't, actually. But I'm not sure if it would work, since I currently have the possibility to 'clear all cookies' and thereby logging out. And then putting the cookies back, to make the user be 'logged in' again. I'm not sure if that would be possible with the global store or using `cy.session`. But I haven't played with it at all, so I don't know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working using `cy.exec()`. This was the solution:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("logInUser", () => {
  let authFileExists = false;
  let authFilePath = './cypress/fixtures/tmp/auth-cookies.json';
  cy.log( authFilePath );
  cy.exec( '[ -f '+authFilePath+' ] && echo "file exists"', {failOnNonZeroExit: false} ).then( (res) => {
    if( res.stdout === 'file exists' ) {
      authFileExists = true;
    }

    if( authFileExists ){
      cy.runManualLogin();
    } else {
      cy.storeAuthCookiesFromTmpFile();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to take a look at `cy.session` ([doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session))

> Cache and restore cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage (i.e. session data) in order to recreate a consistent browser context between tests.

It seems to fit your need.

This is an example of use:

```js
cy.session(name, () => {
  cy.visit('/login')
  cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(name)
  cy.get('[data-test=password]').type('s3cr3t')
  cy.get('form').contains('Log In').click()
  cy.url().should('contain', '/login-successful')
})
```

Comment: I looked into Cypress sessions. And yes - it does add some options, that I hadn't considered. However - it would require a bigger refactoring of my code, to do it in that way.